# INDIRECT() excel - add to formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have need to enter a value that can vary. It is the last row in a column. I add this variable cell to A1. The value is $L$9001

I have the following formula: =VLOOKUP($H4,'week ending 04JUL'!$A$1:$L$9001,3,FALSE)

In A1 I have the value $L$9001. This figure may change hence why I need to add it in and can't use a hardcoded value.

In B1 to test I get the correct output I have: =INDIRECT("A1")
This returns $L$9001 as expected

When I try: =VLOOKUP($H4,'week ending 04JUL'!$A$1:INDIRECT("A1"),3,FALSE)
This returns a #VALUE error.

So I need the value in A1 to replace $L$9001 portion of the formula. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, Indirect works slightly different. Try this:

`=VLOOKUP($H4,Indirect("'week ending 04JUL'!$A$1:"&A1),3,FALSE)`

You put the whole range in the Indirect() field, not just the part you're referring to. Also, note the use of quotes (`"`) starting the Range, wrapping your reference into basically a string that Excel uses.

Comment: would you be able to explain this a little more or point me in the right direction. I have the following: =LARGE(IF(Calculations!$D$4:$D$9003=$F$2,Calculations!$L$4:$L$9003,""),B5). I cover the range as you mention but I get a ref error for the following =LARGE(IF(INDIRECT("Calculations!$D$4:"&$G$2)=$F$2,INDIRECT("Calculations!$L$4:&"$G$3),""),B5)

Comment: G2 and G3 contain the correct values I wish to reference in place of the hardcoded values.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo here in StackOverflow, but your second formula has a misplaced `"` (it's coming AFTER the &, it should come before: `=LARGE(IF(INDIRECT("Calculations!$D$4:"&$G$2)=$F$2,INDIRECT("Calculations!$L$4:"&‌$G$3),""),B5)`